# Center table in presentation (\centering, \begin{center} and {centering} not working)

Tags: tables, beamer, center

I'm using the following beamer as a template:

[Examen Profesional ITAM](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/examen-profesional-itam/xkppkzscmxhc)

And I already tried to center the table with `\centering`, with `\begin{center}` and `{centering}`, `\hspace` and no centering, the table always stays in the same position. I have no idea how to adjust this.

Packages

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=tiny,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=tiny,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}
\usepackage{multido}



\usepackage{array,multirow}

\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{D{,}{,}{#1}} % align numbers on comma (decimal marker)
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\tnoteA{\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}
\newcommand\tnoteB{\tnote{\textdagger}}
\newcommand\XX{$\times$}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[b] macro
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}


% vertical separator macro
\newcommand{\vsep}{
  \column{0.0\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[very thick,black!10] (0,0) -- (0,7.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Table code:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=30]{32 amostras\slash ciclo}

\begin{table}[h]
  
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{adjustbox}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{| c | l d{1,6} *{10}{c} |}
\hline
Caso  & \multicolumn{11}{c|}{32 amostras/ciclo} \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & Método 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytab{Fechamento\\ da chave}} 
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Bloqueio do relé} 
 & Desempenho \\ %\cline{4-11}
 & & & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Ângulo de carregamento} & \\  \cline{4-11}
 & & & 0 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 45 & 60 & \\ 
\hline
\multirow{32}{*}{%
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} S\\O\\B\\ \\C\\A\\R\\G\\A \end{tabular}} 
& \multirow{8}{*}{MPL} 
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MFAAFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MCSLFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{54,16\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MGMA}   
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{93,23\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\smallskip
\small

\smallskip\small
Fonte: Autor

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shrink` option is evil. Don't use it!

It will scale down the content without giving more horizontal space - amongst other problems this will mean that the right margin of the frame will appear bigger and you'll never be able to horizontally centre the content.

Also your table is too height for the frame and not too wide. Using adjustbox to rescale it to the textwidth won't do anything useful.

Instead choose a suitable font size so the table fits on the frame

---

Unrelated:

- beamer automatically loads the `xcolor` package. You mustn't load it again with conflicting options. You can pass whatever xcolour option you like with `xcolor={...}` as class option
- same for `graphicx`. Beamer automatically loads it, you musn't load it again with conflicting options
- your code also wouldn't compile because the `adjustbox` package was missing. But as it didn't make much sense to use it anyway, you could simply not use it.
- don't load one and the same package multiple time, e.g. `multirow`
- you don't need to load `amsmath` and `amssymb`. Beamer already loads them
- it does not make much sense to load the `float` package in a class which does not have a floating mechanism

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor={dvipsnames},demo]{beamer}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{svg}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=tiny,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=tiny,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}
\usepackage{multido}

%\usepackage{adjustbox}


\usepackage{array,multirow}

\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{D{,}{,}{#1}} % align numbers on comma (decimal marker)
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\tnoteA{\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}
\newcommand\tnoteB{\tnote{\textdagger}}
\newcommand\XX{$\times$}

%\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[b] macro
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}


% vertical separator macro
\newcommand{\vsep}{
  \column{0.0\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[very thick,black!10] (0,0) -- (0,7.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{32 amostras\slash ciclo}

\begin{table}
%  \centering
\begin{threeparttable}

%\begin{adjustbox}{\textwidth}
\Tiny
\begin{tabular}{| c | l d{1,6} *{10}{c} |}
\hline
Caso  & \multicolumn{11}{c|}{32 amostras/ciclo} \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & Método 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytab{Fechamento\\ da chave}} 
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Bloqueio do relé} 
 & Desempenho \\ %\cline{4-11}
 & & & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Ângulo de carregamento} & \\  \cline{4-11}
 & & & 0 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 45 & 60 & \\ 
\hline
\multirow{32}{*}{%
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} S\\O\\B\\ \\C\\A\\R\\G\\A \end{tabular}} 
& \multirow{8}{*}{MPL} 
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MFAAFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{100\%} \\ 
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MCSLFO}
    & 0,2      & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{54,16\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \XX\tnoteB & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\ 
\cline{2-12} 
 & \multirow{8}{*}{MGMA}   
    & 0,2      & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & 
   \multirow{8}{*}{93,23\%} \\  
 &  & 0,202083 & \XX & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,204166 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,20625  & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,208333 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,210416 & \XX & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \XX\tnoteA  & \\  
 &  & 0,2125   & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\  
 &  & 0,214583 & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \XX & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{adjustbox}
\smallskip
\small

\smallskip\tiny
Fonte: Autor

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]